# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

i'm trying to install armory on ubuntu 12.04 but it is not working:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i armory_0.88.1-beta_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package armory:i386.
(Reading database ... 222699 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking armory:i386 (from armory_0.88.1-beta_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of armory:i386:
 armory:i386 depends on python-qt4.
 armory:i386 depends on python-twisted.
 armory:i386 depends on python-psutil.
dpkg: error processing armory:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 armory:i386
```

it looked like i needed to install packages `python-qt4`, `python-twisted` and `python-psutil` so i did this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-twisted python-psutil
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 armory:i386 : Depends: python-qt4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-twisted:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: python-psutil:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 python-qt4 : Depends: libqtassistantclient4 (>= 4.6.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: sip-api-8.1
 python-twisted : Depends: python-twisted-conch (>= 1:11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-twisted-mail (>= 11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-twisted-lore (>= 11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-twisted-news (>= 11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-twisted-runner (>= 11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-twisted-words (>= 11.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

for some reason they did not want to install so i did this: (was this a bad move?)

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

and after [a massive amount of output](http://pastebin.com/WbDPnB0t) in which it looked like many packages were removed??? nothing happened. armory still won't run and now i think i have screwed up some other valid packages since i have a lot of empty links with question marks on my unity bar. even the `vim` configuration file seems to have been altered!

help!

(i should also mention that i recently upgraded from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 and that [may not have gone too smoothly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346032/cant-install-bitcoind-in-upgraded-system-due-package-conflicts) for bitcoind)

Comment: You have screwed your system. Now, consider the effort of bringing it back to a functioning state against reinstalling it. Whatever you choose, backup all the important stuff previously, if you haven't already.

Comment: yeah. i'm backing everything up and installing debian 7 instead. i think the thing that broke it is that i forgot my pc is 64bit (its really old so i assumed 32bit) and i tried to install the 32bit armory :(

Answer (score 0):

forward from
https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?13138-BC3-on-64-bit-Ubuntu-14-04

dpkg will not install dependencies, that is why it won't run.

The easy way to install it is to double click in the file manager to launch Ubuntu Software Center, then click Install.

To install from a terminal after the attempted install with `dpkg`:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcompare
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi bcompare-3.3.10.17762_i386.deb
```

If you hadn't previously attempted to install Beyond Compare, the `sudo apt-get remove bcompare` would not be necessary.